# App.js:13 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, get, fetch-api

Sending a  fetch request to this API, though as the title states, keep getting unexpected end of input and I can't figure out why. Any solutions?

```
import './App.css';

import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';        

const ART_API = "https://api.harvardartmuseums.org"

function App() {
  const [anime ,setAnime] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => { 
    fetch(ART_API, {mode: 'no-cors'})
      
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => { console.log(data)})
                          
  }, []);}
```

Comment: You forgot a `}` in the end

Comment: Oh, I didn't post the correct code, I have the } in my source. Thank you though.

Comment: That URL doesn't return JSON. It redirects to the home page of the web site.

Comment: I tried with an another URL, and still getting the same res, for Example this ANIME url    https://api.aniapi.com